# Reading ICS file via Salesforce Email Handler

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

we have a request to read ICS file and generate activity in salesforce. I was able to from Google Calendar, Mac Outlook client via reading text attachment of ics file. But when with Windows Outlook client it doesn't give this information anywhere.(that include TextAttachment, BinaryAttachment and plainBodyText). Any pointer to handle this request is really appreciated